# where does R allocate data and array?

Tags: r, memory

I am doing research on R (language) and want to know if it allocates array on stack or heap. Or is it different cases to cases?
Also, I want to know what categories of arrays are supported in R.(e.g. static, fixed stack dynamic, fixed heap dynamic, heap dynamic)

I know that it does support heterogeneous array type by converting lists into frame.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c("red", "white", "red", NA)
c <- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
mydata <- data.frame(a,b,c)
typeof(mydata[[3]][1])
```

I thought it would give me double intead if list.
My question is

1. Where does R allocate arrays and data?
2. what categories of arrays are
   supported in R?(e.g. static, fixed stack dynamic, fixed heap
   dynamic, heap dynamic)

Comment: you might try here -- http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/base/html/gctorture.html or here https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/xls/changes/changes/node7.html

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `mydata[3, 1]` instead of `mydata[3][1]`? Because `typeof(mydata[3, 1])` is a double (the number `3`). Plus, it doesn't make much sense to run `mydata[3][1]` since it is the same as `mydata[3]`. What element were you trying to index?

Comment: The proper access to the element of the data frame `mydata[1,3]` or the element of the list (any data frame is a list) `mydata[[3]][1]` will give `logical` value `TRUE`